# How to associate an entity view mode with a path? (Commerce product entity)

Tags: nodes, commerce, uri, entities

I created a view mode for a Commerce product entity with http://drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode , now I would like to associate this with a path like myproduct/[entity_id] , so I can attach meta tags and everything else to it.

How would I go about this? Essentially, I am trying to avoid using a product display node for a product entity.

Comment: Just for curiosity, why are you trying to avoid product display ?

Comment: Good question. I find it unnecessary and overly complicates the site. I think Commerce should have sticked with nodes as products... I fail to see why 4 fields( SKU, price etc) merit an entirely different entity than a simple node that is fully integrated with Drupal. Entities may be a good idea for D8 but for D7 they are crap as most contrib modules are still catching up... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own entity view path with

[hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)

e.g, something like

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu
 */
function mymodule_menu(){
  $items = array()
  $items['myproduct/%myproduct'] = array(
    'title callback' => 'myproduct_page_title',
    'title arguments' => array(1),
    'page callback' => 'myproduct_page_view',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'myproduct_access',
    'access arguments' => array('view', 1),
  );
}

/**
 * My Product page view callback
 */
function myproduct_page_view($myproduct){
  drupal_set_title($myproduct->title);
  $uri = entity_uri('myproduct', $myproduct);
  // Set the node path as the canonical URL to prevent duplicate content.
  drupal_add_html_head_link(array('rel' => 'canonical', 'href' => url($uri['path'], $uri['options'])), TRUE);
  // Some example to get entity display
  $view_mode = 'full';
  return myproduct_entity_view($myproduct, $view_mode);
}
```

See [node_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_menu/7) node/%node for example node view implementation.

Nevertheless, I'd recommend using standard product display nodes for product display.